# Columns blank after join

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 `df` like `df1, df2, df3` and they read a `.csv` file. I want to combine `df1 & df2` and then have the `result` do a lookup on `df3` and pull the values that are the same in a certain `key` that's both in `df3` and `result`. So basically a vlookup.

This is how I concatenated `df1`&`df2`:

```
result = pd.concat(frames,keys=['data1','data2'])
```

I performed the `merge` like this:

```
result = pd.merge(result, df3, left_on='ProducerID', right_index=True, how='left', sort=False)
```

But my results are these:

```
        Key_x   otherColumns    Key_y   otherColumns
L   0   5763460 NaN             NaN     NaN
L   1   5926058 NaN             NaN     NaN
L   2   5052233 NaN             NaN     NaN
L   3   5526565 NaN             NaN     NaN
L   4   5059073 NaN             NaN     NaN
L   5   5975975 NaN             NaN     NaN
```

I should mention, `key` is not in the index. I abbreviated the data. `key` is just a column in the middle of my data.

And these are snippets of what my data files look like:

```
df1                 
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column n…   Key     Column …n
data1       data        data        data        5763460 data
data2       data        data        data        5926058 data
data1       data        data        data        5052233 data

df2                 
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column n…   Key     Column …n
data1       data        data        data        5763460 data
data1       data        data        data        5926058 data
data2       data        data        data        5052233 data

df3                 
Key     Column 1    Column 2            
5763460 data        data            
5926058 data        data            
5052233 data        data

result                  
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column n…   Key     Column …n
data1       data        data        data        5763460 data
data1       data        data        data        5926058 data
data2       data        data        data        5052233 data
```

So `result` will look just like `df1` just larger and grouped by the contents of `Column 1` which are `data1` and `data2`

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ;)

Comment: @MaxU how about now?? :3

Comment: It's still not very clear... What are `['genericName','otherName']`? `df1 == df2`, so if people would use them for answering your question they would have 3 duplicates as the result of `pd.concat(...)` and so on... The key word in my first comment was - `reproducible`. You should try your code against your sample DFs and you didn't specify your desired data set ... ;)

Comment: Those are just placeholders, I'm using them there to group by those names. So I end up with a datafile grouped by name1 and then name2. I edited the question to reflect this comment

Comment: Usually if posters don't provide reproducible input data sets and their desired data set, then it ends with the following comment coming from the Original Poster (OP) - it's not what I need / was expecting to get / etc... Look, people will invest their time in order to help you to find an answer, so put some effort into reproducible samples / examples. No offends, OK ? ;)

Comment: I got you man! I hope I didn't sound like I'm complaining. I guess I was just trying to make it a brief question. I thought maybe I was missing some syntax and didn't think it was gonna be more involved than that.

Comment: looking at your resulting DF - you don't seem to have matching rows in your "right" DF (in the `pd.merge()`) hence NaNs

Comment: But that's the thing, I know for a fact that the key is in both the `result` and `df3` dataframes. So I should be able to pull the values that are in `df3['column1']`. I thought this was how you do a vlookup in pandas? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way

Comment: Maybe... We would need to see a __reproducible__ data sets in order to give you a qualified answer. Good luck!